# Storing int variable from user into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, user-input

I am fairly new to c programming, and also this forum but I thought I would give it a try. What I want to do is have a user enter a 4 digit number. From there i want to take the number and store it in an array, so as i could call arr[2] when I need it and so on and so on. Thanks in advance for any help!

I would really like to know what is going on here. Thanks again

Comment: You're parsing out a single `int` value.. `2345`. If you want single digits you need to pull them one char at a time from a line buffer (or `fgetc()`) and convert the *single* chars to `int`, then store each in  your target array. You may want to validate each is, in fact, a digit char prior to converting. Finally, please return something besides vapor form `int main()`. You declared it right. Return `EXIT_SUCCESS` on success, `EXIT_FAILURE` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do what you think it does. `scanf` reads a line from the console. `%d` matches a *number* (i.e. 123), not a *digit* (i.e. 1, 2, 3). You call `printf` in a loop, not `scanf` (i.e. you capture one number and you print it multiple times).

Actually, I see it is more than that - you are assuming `integer` in C++ means digit. Your array of 4 integers does not hold a 4 digit number - it holds four separate integers, each of which can be (usually) from -2147483648 to +2147483648.

The thing is, it's not easy to break a number into digits - because "digits" are base 10 (decimal) while a computer thinks in base 2 (binary). What we can do instead is read and write the number and digits as *text*, instead. Read the integer as a string, and write each digit as a character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[4];

    //get input as text, instead of as a number
    printf ("Please enter a 4 digit number: ");
    scanf ("%s", input);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        //print as char instead of as number
        printf ("%c\n", input[i]);
    }
}
```

This code is not perfect. If the user entered "blah" it will print "b" "l" "a" "h" instead of complain about non-numeric input. If the user enters more than 4 characters, our array of characters to hold the number will overflow causing serious security risks and a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities exist to implementing the behavior you want. Here's one way of doing it:

```
int arr[4];
int i;
char var1[4];

printf("Please enter a 4 digit number: ");
scanf("%s", var1);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    arr [i] = var1[i] - '0'; // convert char to int
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

var1 is an integer and you are storing it in each element of the integer array arr, hence the output

If you want to store each number as a character, use fgets, or if you want to store it a number, do

```
i=0;
while(var1){
     arr[len-i-1] = var1%10; //len is 4 in your case
     var1 /= 10;
     i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked `scanf` to read an integer value.  You might want to read a string instead.

In a pinch, you can use `fgets`:

```
char number[5];
if( fgets(number, sizeof(number), stdin) != NULL )
{
    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        printf( "%c\n", number[i] );
    }
}
```